# ¿Cómo hacer correctamente una operación de Linq con un for y luego devolverlo a la vista?

Tags: c#, linq

una pregunta, estoy armando una tabla con ciertos valores que tengo dentro de un array, el tema es que estoy usando linq para armarlo pero me tira error al mostrarlo en la vista:

Declaración del array:

`int[] myInts = null;`

Operación que quiero recorrer:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < myInts.Length; i++)
{
                   var qav = q.ParametrosCanalesValores.Where(x => x.Parametros.ModuloId == myInts[i]).ToList();
}
```

"qav" lo tengo que declarar ahi porque no me deja declararlo afuera como null

Hasta ahi todo bien, no hay error en principio.
El tema es que si hago eso, aunque este correcto, me tira error cuando devuelvo la Lista en el return view, me dice que "qav" no existe en el contexto actual:

```
using (qEntities)
{                    
  return View(qav);
}
```

Eh intentado con soluciones que me plantearon, como hacer una lista, pero no funciona, entra al for pero no se agrega ningun valor a "qav":

```
 List<ParametrosCanalesValores> qav = new List<ParametrosCanalesValores>();


                for(int i = 0; i < myInts.Length; i++)
                {
                    //var qav = qavant.ParametrosCanalesValores.Where(x => x.Parametros.ModuloId == myInts[i]).ToList();
                    qav.AddRange(qavant.ParametrosCanalesValores.Where(x => x.Parametros.ModuloId == myInts[i]).ToList());
                    //qav = qavant.ParametrosCanalesValores.Where(x => x.Parametros.ModuloId == myInts[i]).ToList();
                }
```

Les dejo el codigo por si lo quieren ver:

```
 public ActionResult AltaDatos()
        {
            try
            {               
                parametros = Session["parametros"] as string;
                qEntities = new AdminEntities();
                ModulosActivados = Session["modulosActivos"] as string;
                arrayParams = ModulosActivados.Split(',');
                myInts = arrayParams.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();              

                for(int i = 0; i < myInts.Length; i++)
                {
                   var qav = q.ParametrosCanalesValores.Where(x => x.Parametros.ModuloId == myInts[i]).ToList();
                }

                using (qEntities)
                {                    
                    return View(qav);
                }
            }
            }
```

Caulquier ayuda me viene de 10,

Desde ya muchas gracias y avisen si hay algo que no se entendió

Comment: Pero q es lo que hace tu consulta?

Comment: Arma una lista con Parametros que tengan un ID igual a los que estén dentro de myInt[ ]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes declarar qav fuera como una lista de Personas, así de paso no esta nulla en el caso de que necesites recorrerla con un for o algo parecido

```
List<Personas> qav = new List<Personas>();
```

ya con la variable insttanciada en tu ciclo for actualmente estas reemplazando en cada iteración, lo que supongo es que quieres irle agregando, entonces sugiero que cambies la igualación por un AddRange()

```
 for(int i = 0; i < myInts.Length; i++)
 {
   qav.AddRange(Personas.Edad.Where(x => x.Edad == myInts[i]).ToList());
 }
```

Ojala te sirva.

Comment: Me tira el siguiente error: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.', que me puede estar faltando? Ademas, "qav" se me queda en 0, no entra nada

Comment: tomando en cuenta que dices que qav queda en 0 me da a entender que si se instancio y por lo tanto si debe de tener el metodo AddRange, creo que entonces tienes que validar que tanto Personas como la lista edad Edad no sean null

Comment: no hay nada en null, de hecho, entra al for, pero al momento de agregarle los valores a qav sale y se va directo al catch